# assigning integers to inner lists

Tags: list-manipulation

Consider a asymmetric list which has been obtained from a `NSolve` command

```
{{{w -> 0.25}}, {{w -> 0.05}}, {{w -> 0.190065}, {w -> 
    0.0182686}}, {{w -> 0.0404842}, {w -> 0.0086731}}, {{w -> 
    0.156634}, {w -> 0.015429}, {w -> 0.00478921}}, {{w -> 
    0.0344873}, {w -> 0.00753932}, {w -> 0.00292085}}, {{w -> 
    0.134788}, {w -> 0.0134812}, {w -> 0.00424987}, {w -> 
    0.00191167}}, {{w -> 0.0302949}, {w -> 0.00671401}, {w -> 
    0.0026321}, {w -> 0.00131905}}, {{w -> 0.119177}, {w -> 
    0.012046}, {w -> 0.00383985}, {w -> 0.0017433}, {w -> 
    0.000948279}}, {{w -> 0.0271667}, {w -> 0.00608107}, {w -> 
    0.00240521}, {w -> 0.00121431}, {w -> 0.00070449}}}
```

How can I build a list using above list so that assign an integer to number of each inner list in an ordered way,where smallest number in each inner list(they are in descending order) get 0, for example for above list we must build a list as follows

```
{{{0}},{{0}},{{1},{0}},{{1},{0}},{{2},{1},{0}} and etc}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Ordering /@ Values@list - 1

Reverse /@ Range /@ Length /@ list - 1
```

> {{0}, {0}, {1, 0}, {1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {2, 1, 0}, {3, 2, 1, 0}, {3, 2, 
>     1, 0}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 0}, {4, 3, 2, 1, 0}}

Or

```
Map[List, Ordering /@ Values@list, {2}] - 1
```

> {{{0}}, {{0}}, {{1}, {0}}, {{1}, {0}}, {{2}, {1}, {0}}, {{2}, {1}, 
>   {0}}, {{3}, {2}, {1}, {0}}, {{3}, {2}, {1}, {0}}, {{4}, {3}, {2}, 
>   {1}, {0}}, {{4}, {3}, {2}, {1}, {0}}}